# How to import openai package using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model

I am getting the below error message when importing openai as ai using google jupyter notebook:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3f86bb4abbfc> in <module>
----> 1 import openai as ai

   /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 import os as _os
----> 6 from typing_extensions import override
      7 
      8 from . import types

ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'typing_extensions' 
(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like [an issue](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/751) is already reported.

Comment: What's the `typing_extensions` version you are using?

Comment: Could you share your pip env? (pip list env)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a problem related to versions that seem incompatible.

I tested a Python 3.8 environment and openai==1.6.1 seems to work fine. Try to install the following pinned version.

```
python -m pip install openai==1.6.1
```

EDIT:

pd: typing_extension is well known to cause a lot of dependcy problems, as this one. I suggest you:

1. Pin your version in a requirements.txt to ensure your project work as expected. Here are mines from a recent project. If the above suggestion does not work, use this snippet as the requirements.txt.

```
python-dotenv~=1.0.0
azure-core~=1.29.5
azure-identity~=1.15.0
chainlit~=0.7.604
openai~=1.3.5
langchain~=0.0.339
pypdf~=3.17.1
python-docx~=1.1.0
faiss-cpu
tiktoken
pysqlite3-binary
```

2. It is almost sure that you will face similar issues soon. So, I suggest you to search the Error trace on Google and dig into the forums (Github issues, Stackoverflow, etc) for answers. For example, you could type the following in google:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'typing_extensions'
```

And you would find this Giuthub issue: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/751
which could help you clarify what it is happening.